# Managing Visual Studio 2008 VB.Net Project References in Visual SourceSafe 2005

Tags: visual-studio-2008, dll, reference, visual-sourcesafe

hi
I'm a member of a 5 personnel software team and we are working on a VB.Net 2008 project and the project has been added to VS 2005.

The problem is every time each member opens his Visual studio on his owm machine to develop the project and gets the latest version of the project, almost all "References" have got a yellow exclamation mark -so he gets many number of erros- and he has to delete them manually and add them again and then check the project in.

What causes this? Is something wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your references are outside of the solution/project and are added as an absolute path.

Try moving the dll folder inside the solution/project and reference them again, if you look at the project file you should see the references added as relative ones ie. ..\lib\mydll.dll